# Java dbus ModemManager

Tags: dbus

I'm tring to access without luck dbus from Java for ModemManager.
Im using dbus-java from https://github.com/hypfvieh/dbus-java.
What I've done so far is:

1. Get a connection to the Bus

`DBusConnection conn = DBusConnection.getConnection(DBusConnection.DBusBusType.SYSTEM)`;

2. Imported Introspection xml, generated on device (But I'm not sure this work is ok)..
3. Tried a connection to the specific bus to handle informations:

```
Modem modem = conn.getRemoteObject("org.freedesktop.ModemManager1", "/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem", Modem.class)
```

4. Connect an handler to get info:

```
conn.addSigHandler(Modem.StateChanged.class, new DBusSigHandler<Modem.StateChanged>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Modem.StateChanged s) {
                        System.out.println("State" + s._new);
                    }
                });
```

Result.. no event are fired. On device i see (using dbus-monitor --system) that events are fired for all the time i run.

for example, in dbus-monitor i see:

```
signal time=1615482074.152996 sender=:1.5 -> destination=(null destination) serial=478 path=/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.freedesktop.ModemManager1.Modem"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "SignalQuality"
         variant             struct {
               uint32 80
               boolean true
            }
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]
```

Someone can point me to the right direction? I'm sure Im doing something wrong.
Thanks
Gianmaria

Answer (score 1):

The second string in this setup is wrong:

```
Modem modem = conn.getRemoteObject("org.freedesktop.ModemManager1", "/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem", Modem.class)
```

It should be the full object path; e.g. for modem at index 0:

```
Modem modem = conn.getRemoteObject("org.freedesktop.ModemManager1", "/org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0", Modem.class)
```